# Finding coefficient of generating functions

Tags: combinatorics

I have the equation

$$(1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^k+\ldots)(1+x^2+x^4+\ldots+x^{2k}+\ldots)(x^2+x^3)$$

how of I find the coefficent of $x^{24}$. I know to condense this down to

$$\frac1{1-x}\cdot\frac1{1-x^2}\cdot x(1+x)$$

but I don't know what to do after that

Comment: Note that the first displayed line is not an *equation*; it’s just an *expression*.

Comment: Do you know how to determine the coefficient of $x^k$ in the expansion of $(1-x)^{-2}$.  If not, you can look up binomial series.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: There is cancellation, $(1-x^2)=(1-x)(1+x)$. And $x^2+x^3=x^2(1+x)$.

So we end  up with $\dfrac{x^2}{(1-x)^2}$.

Now everything is straightforward. The coefficients for $\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^2}$ can be found by a direct computation of $(1+x+x^2+\cdots)(1+x+x^2+\cdots)$, or by noticing that $\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^2}$ is the derivative of $\frac{1}{1-x}$, and differentiating $1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots$ term by term.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way: the coefficient of $x^{24}$ is the number of integer solutions to $$a+b+c=24$$ where $a\ge0$; $b\ge0$ is even; and $c$ is $2$ or $3$.

If $c=2$, then we have $a+b=22$. There are $12$ values of $b$ (namely, $0,2,\dots,22$), and for each, a value of $a$. So, $12$ solutions so far.

If $c=3$, then $a+b=21$, so there are $11$ values of $b$ ($0,2,\dots,20$); for each, there's a value of $a$, so, another $11$ solutions.

All told, $12+11=23$ solutions, so that's the coefficient you're looking for.